# Changing C# Coordinate System to be RtL

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, gdi+

I have a dozen of code editors written in Left-to-Right layout (for LTR languages).

I'm thinking if I could change C# coordinate system so that x = 0 being at the right rather than left, then I would not change any code written to render LTR.

Is this possible in .NET? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change layout for all Controls or just text editor controls?

Comment: I want to change all controls, but those code editors graphics code is written in LTR, so that changing `RightToLeft` property doesn't affect

Comment: Every control like editors have this properties.what is your control?

Comment: `AvalonEdit` and `FastColoredTextBox`. I've tried to change this property without success

Comment: Did you change `FlowDirection` property?`FlowDirection = LeftToRight, TextAlignment = Right`

Comment: Yes. But this makes either the cursor at the leftmost all the time, or the `{, (, [, <` at the end of a line make them at the right (will they should be at the left, since they are at line end)

Comment: When I change `Form.RightToLeftLayout` to true, x = 0 is at the right. But this property doesn't exist in other controls

Comment: In wpf window you can use FlowDirection to change coordinate.

Comment: Do you want to use this control as a code editor?

Comment: If I can use it then no problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably missing something obvious but I don't see how changing a coordinate axis is going to help you in this case.

If you are not after proper support for RTL languages then realigning all text controls to have the text Right Aligned would be sufficient.

But editable controls where user input is expected would also need to output the text in reverse order. The caret would need to move along the X axis toward the -ve side. To support this you would probably need to do some code changes in the controls internals.

Personally, I've never seen a RTL controls that would simply flip an axis to switch from LTR mode.

My two cents.

Comment: So How can I change the text align?